# Tomcat/Catalina MBean operation to get session attribute objects

Tags: java, session, tomcat, jmx, mbeans

My WebApp stores User tokens in the Session.  I was trying to view these tokens using the MBean interface (via JConsole)

The Tomcat/Catalina MBean with ObjectName "Catalina:type=Manager" has an invokeable method `getSessionAttribute`, but since the method returns only strings, it gives me the String value "MyTokenClass@234234" instead of the actual token Object...

Is there any way to access these custom objects in the session?  I could try writing my own MBean but the one included in Tomcat's Manager properly tracks live (vs. expired) sessions, and I wouldn't like to have to duplicate this.